# Blocking the output until input is finished using threads java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm making a simple console chat application using sockets and threads. I have two different threads for sending and reading the messages. Everything works fine except one thing. I have to block the reader thread if I'm currently inside the sending thread.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    input = In.readLine();

    while (!input.equals("x")) {
        if (input.isEmpty()) {
            Out.println("----------------------------");
            Out.print("Your message: ");
            message = In.readLine();
            Out.println("----------------------------");

            writer.println(message);
            writer.flush();
        }

        input = In.readLine();
    }
}
```

Here is the reading thread

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while ((receivedMessage = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Out.println("Received message: " + receivedMessage);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {

    }
}
```

What I have to do is following: If I'm currently writing a message "message = In.readLine()", and in the meantime I receive some messages, these should be displayed only after I finish the input.

Comment: Add all incoming messages to a queue, and then when the input is done, process the inbound message queue and display them.

Comment: The only thing I'm allowed to use are following: threads and (synchronized) methods that come along - wait, notify, notifyAll, join ect. Is there a possibility to things in such way? - Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to do this.  Perhaps the simplest would be to use a monitor to lock display of received messages while typing a message to be sent.  Basically have an `Object` - you could call it displayLock or something like that - and put within blocks synchronizing on this `Object` the first four lines of the `if` block in the sending thread and the `Out.println` line in the receiving thread.  That way only one of the two synchronized blocks could proceed at a time.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much!!! Could you recommend any good articles on synchronization and multithreading? Thanks once again

Comment: There are entire books written on the subject.  The key things to understand are (1) how the primitives, like `synchronized` in Java, work, and (2) that they are required, and you can't get away with hoping a race condition will be infrequent.  One good article to start with is this one:  http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074979/java-concurrency/double-checked-locking--clever--but-broken.html .